# how do i tell that an instance in sequelize has never been updated

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have node js application where I need to do something if an instance in sequelize has been updated before or delete if the instance has never been updated. any ideas

Comment: Such information should be stored in a record itself (or in a separate table).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **hooks** in sequalize

[here](https://sequelize.org/v7/manual/hooks.html) you can read about the hooks.